# Merging Polygons using ST_Multi ST_Union group by column value

Tags: postgis, polygon

I'm trying to merge polygons  together to form a larger 1 and I'm getting some odd results

In the  picture the red is giving the correct outline but there are 11 identical polygons I was expecting only 1 (this is related to the number of smaller polygons to be merged) eg the number of polygons with the same gd.gid_4 value

Can anyone say  what I'm doing wrong?  I'm running this query in PostgreSQL and viewing in qgis

Please note using "*" for clarity here

```
INSERT INTO new_table (*)
SELECT g.*,gd.geometry
FROM gadm36 g
JOIN(
    SELECT gd.gid_4 AS gid_4,
    ST_Multi(ST_Union(gd.geom) ) As geometry
    FROM gadm36 AS gd
WHERE  gd.gid_0 = 'FRA'
    GROUP BY gd.gid_4

) gd ON g.gid_4 = gd.gid_4;
```

[image: Merging polygons]

Comment: The CROSS JOIN looks like it will cause duplication of the result of the union

Comment: `g` has 11 rows with the same `gid_4`; to each one of those, the matching row of the inner query will be joined. Now, the inner query alone does pretty much exactly what you want by itself, or so I think, except that you'd need to `GROUP BY` any non-aggregate column you expect in the output (-> `g.*`). If all column values except the `geom` are equal for those 11 rows, you can just `GROUP BY` all of them. If not, then logically there is no way around aggregation, or duplication, or not selecting them at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subquery generates 1 multipolygon for each gid_4. However, joining on the condition `g.gid_4 = gd.gid_4` multiplies your rows by the number of rows of each gid_4 value, 11 in this case, resulting in 11 identical rows with a multipolygon.

Since you only want 1 multipolygon per gid_4, I suggest using only the subquery:

```
SELECT gd.gid_4 AS gid_4,
    ST_Multi(ST_Union(gd.geom) ) As geometry
FROM gadm36 AS gd
WHERE  gd.gid_0 = 'FRA'
GROUP BY gd.gid_4
```

And add any additional fields that you need in both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statements. Make sure the fields you add only contain one unique value per gid_4, otherwise you'll need to exclude those fields or use them in an aggregate function.

Comment: I fixed it: FYI in my select list I had gid this is unique therefor producing multiple rows